# How to disable open_basedir and allow_url_fopen in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, open-basedir

I'm currently working on a PrestaShop website and noticed that one of my addon does not work when `open_basedir` and `allow_url_fopen` are enabled.

How to disable `openbase_dir` and `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini on my local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to comment out `open_basedir` in `php.ini` file and restart the server.

As:

```
;open_basedir
```

and this line in the `.htaccess` file

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

or you can add this line in `php.ini` file

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
```